# Got problem with python using while function

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm student and begginer in python and I have a problem. I have from a matrix 6 by 6 do some operations on it. I have to do for each values of each part (11 * matrix_val)%37 but my counters are not working properly ...

Here is my code :

```
m = [[36, 19, 27, 36, 7, 10], [2, 18, 3, 33, 2, 21], [26, 27, 4, 22, 30, 31], [29, 36, 7, 20, 6, 30], [30, 6, 14, 23, 15, 13], [22, 10, 10, 35, 15, 22]]
i = 0 #matrix jumping
j = 0 #scan the matrix
k = 1
somme = 0

while k < 24:
    while i < 6:
        while j < 6:
            m[i][j] = (11 * m[i][j])%37
            print(i,j,k)
            j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    k = k + 1
j = 0
i = 0
print(m)
```

But when I chek my counters, only "j" is increasing but "i" and "k" are not as tou can see here :

```
isatix@isatix-MS-7A34:~/python/ceinture/20 points$ python3 matrice.py
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 2 1
0 3 1
0 4 1
0 5 1
[[26, 24, 1, 26, 3, 36], [2, 18, 3, 33, 2, 21], [26, 27, 4, 22, 30, 31], [29, 36, 7, 20, 6, 30], [30, 6, 14, 23, 15, 13], [22, 10, 10, 35, 15, 22]]
isatix@isatix-MS-7A34:~/python/ceinture/20 points$
```

So maybe i'm doing something wrong but I can't see it ^^ 
Some one has an idea ?

EDIT : ISSUE RESOLVED :

here is the code working fine :

```
m = [[36, 19, 27, 36, 7, 10], [2, 18, 3, 33, 2, 21], [26, 27, 4, 22, 30, 31], [29, 36, 7, 20, 6, 30], [30, 6, 14, 23, 15, 13], [22, 10, 10, 35, 15, 22]]
i = 0 #saute de matrice en matrice
j = 0 #parcour la matrice
k = 1
somme = 0

while k < 24:
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < 6:
        while j < 6:
            m[i][j] = (11 * m[i][j])%37
            print(i,j,k)
            j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
        j = 0
    k = k + 1
print(m)
```

Comment: you aren't resetting your counters at the right level. Once the inner loop runs, `j` becomes 6. after that, it never gets reset, so it never prints. the counters however increment just fine.

Comment: Nothing resets `j` or `i` after they finish looping, so once they reach their max values, the loops that use those variables won't run at all, so nothing will get printed.

Comment: Ok thank you guys. I going to fix it and come back whith some better results :)

Comment: @David look at my answer. your answer is still a little messy

Comment: Yes i saw it and i fixed my issue juste few moments before your post ^^ But thankyou anyway @rhavelka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting your `i` and `j` equal to 0 in the wrong spots. Before tackling 3 loops, you should get comfortable looping through 2 loops. Also, should your `k` start at 1 or 0?

```
m = [[36, 19, 27, 36, 7, 10], 
     [2, 18, 3, 33, 2, 21], 
     [26, 27, 4, 22, 30, 31], 
     [29, 36, 7, 20, 6, 30], 
     [30, 6, 14, 23, 15, 13], 
     [22, 10, 10, 35, 15, 22]]
k = 1
somme = 0

while k < 24:
    i = 0 #matrix jumping
    while i < 6:
        j = 0 #scan the matrix
        while j < 6:
            m[i][j] = (11 * m[i][j])%37
            print(i,j,k)
            j += 1
        i += 1
    k += 1

print(m)
```